# New Java Array of Strings in Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I'm writing a high-performance nashorn application, and what I'd really like to do is find something equivalent to `new String[]{"foo", "bar", "noise"}` from within javascript.  The cost of converting from a javascript array to a java array is prohibitively expensive, shows up on every flame graph.

The best I've found up to this point is:

`{var StringArray = Java.type('java.lang.String[]');"); var arr = new StringArray(3)); var arr[0] = 'foo'; var arr[1] = 'bar'; var arr[2] = 'noise'; arr;`}

But that's super ugly.  Is this the best syntax available to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing really anything about nashorn, is it possible to create a method (call it `createStringArray(String...)`) in Java that takes a varargs String parameter, and just returns the parameter?  When you would call that (`var arr = createStringArray('foo', 'bar', 'noise');`), does that have the performance you'd look for, or does it end up doing the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `Java.to()`:

```
Java.to(["foo", "bar", "noise"],"java.lang.String[]");
```

If this code works for you (it does for me, tested with jjs 1.8.0_51), you can create a function to ease the code readability. Like this:

```
function toJavaStringArray(a) {
  return Java.to(a,"java.lang.String[]");
}
```