# Why is this syntax not working in creating Java String array with nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I see [New Java Array of Strings in Nashorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193667/new-java-array-of-strings-in-nashorn), and find the solution.

But I just wonder why my origin code throws exception:

```
var JStringArray = Java.type("java.lang.String[]");
var validExtensions = new JStringArray(".java", ".class", ".jar", ".xml");
```

The exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor [Ljava.lang.String; with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in ~/scriptMonkey/js/samples/FileStatistics.js at line number 9
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at Debugger.main(Debugger.java:16)
Caused by: ~/scriptMonkey/js/samples/FileStatistics.js:9 TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor [Ljava.lang.String; with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures.
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:185)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:172)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornStaticClassLinker.checkNullConstructor(NashornStaticClassLinker.java:108)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornStaticClassLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornStaticClassLinker.java:96)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:253)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$1$FileStatistics.:program(~/scriptMonkey/js/samples/FileStatistics.js:9)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.evaluateSource(Context.java:1222)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.load(Context.java:839)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.load(Global.java:1545)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:449)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: And why didn't you include the exception? That's **why** it won't work.

Comment: @Whoever downvote after one month the problem is solved, the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the JStringArray constructor, you can pass only number of elements of the array.

```
var JStringArray = Java.type("java.lang.String[]");
var validExtensions = new JStringArray(4);
validExtensions[0] = ".java";
...
```

All Java array type objects are constructors that accept single argument that is the "length" of the array.

Comment: Is it because of Java or Nashorn implementation, that the first parameter has to be the size of Array? After all we can do something like  ` final String[] strings;
        strings = new String[]{"1"};` in Java code.

Comment: Yes - different language, different choices made! As someone stated in the other Q/A hyperlinked, there is Java.to function that can convert JS array to Java array. That may be convenient for your case. If you strongly feel about this, you may submit a rfe with OpenJDK.